# When running a typical LAMP stack for a public website on EC2, what is the proper firewall setting for port 3306?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

I'm reviewing the security groups on my EC2 Ubuntu instance that runs a public website on LAMP. Presently my ports are as follows:

```
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
3306 (MYSQL)    0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm thinking it should be possible to tighten up a bit on the mysql port as the connections are only made locally. Any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your MySQL instance is running on the same instance and is *only* answering local connections, then you don't need any entries for port 3306 at all in your security group config.

Also, for defence in depth, you should set the `bind-address` MySQL configuration directive to `127.0.0.1` (probably the default, but worth checking).

**EDIT**

You've two routes for opening up access from outside:

- Set `bind-address` back to `0.0.0.0`, and add `a.b.c.d/32` to your security group (whatever that IP might be) to allow access on port 3306. However, this is a basic method that transmits in plaintext.
- Use SSH port forwarding. Logging in to your shell with `ssh -L33306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@host` will let you then launch `mysql -h localhost -P 33306` on your local machine to connect through the tunnel. `-bind-address` doesn't need to be opened up in this case, since the mysql connection is still local (the local port can be whatever you like so long as the `-L` and `-P` arguments match) . This will give you a more secure route in, and you can configure SSH to use private keys, for added protection.

Comment: SmallClanger, thanks for the info. That's what I was looking for. Now, what if I wanted to open up mysql to a known external IP. I assume that would be entered in the AWS ports settings. But what about the bind-address directive?

Comment: Added in some more to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hardening is very important.

1. For MySQL, set the *source*, same as the security group. ( Eg: If the security group "default" has id "sg-1234s3gd", specify sg-1234s3gd as source for portrange 3306 ).
2. Install [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) for Apache and subscribe to CoreRulesSet. If possible Rate Limit the requests per IP.
3. Disable RootLogin in SSH. Allow only key based authentication, Change SSH listen port if possible.
4. Run a security assessment using [Bastille](http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/).